# WildFly returning just a file name

Tags: java, maven, jsf-2, wildfly

I've recently attempted to use WildFly instead of TomEE as the container for my JSF bassed web app. It's a basic app that serves a page that has a couple of fields that can be saved to a DB.

It worked fine in TomEE, but since I've attempted building with Maven and deploying to WildFly I haven't had much luck.

When I attempt to navigate to the first page (http://localhost:8080/firstflight-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/firstflight/hello.jsf) WildFly is simply returning a blank page with the following text printed out:

> /firstflight-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/firstflight/hello.jsp

Of course the first thing that one notices is that it seems to have found the page because the extension is `jsp`, not `jsf` which was used to request the page. Also requesting a non-existant page gives a 404, so something must be working here.

Let me know if more info will help and I'll try and provide it.

**UPDATE:** I've been asked to include the entire `web.xml` so here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/hello.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>xhtml</extension>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Could you post your entire web.xml?

Comment: What if you create a 3.0 web.xml instead of a 2.5 one?

Answer (score -1):

Something does not appear right with the url. /firstflight-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT looks like the name of the uploaded war not the web context. Without knowing more details about your application I would have thought your url should be http://localhost:8080/firstflight/hello.jsp.

I also note that in the web.xml your welcome page is a xhtml page and you have specified the servlet-mapping url-pattern as *.jsf. If your pages are .xhtml then this needs to be *.xhtml so that your application knows which pages are Faces pages and then the url will be http://localhost:8080/firstflight/hello.xhtml

Graham

Comment: The name of the war **is** the web context if not provided otherwise and the servlet mapping is also valid